# Grouped points in ggplot next to each other

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

I am trying to recreat the following plot using ggplot2: [image]

But I am not able to separate the points into the different groups. What I get something similar to this:

```
library(ggplot2)

mpg %>%  ggplot(aes(class, displ)) +
  geom_jitter(aes(fill=drv), width=.09, shape =21)
```

[image]

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for `position_jitterdodge` which is an argument of `geom_point`

```r
library(ggplot2)


mpg |>  ggplot(aes(class, displ)) +
  geom_point(aes(fill=drv), position = position_jitterdodge(jitter.width = 0.05, jitter.height = 0.5, dodge.width = 0.4), shape =21)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-02-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>